# Crossover related query

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I've 3 lines for bull, bear & signal.

I've 2 conditions related to crossover given below.

1. `adx_strongbuy = ta.crossover(bull, bear)` and `ta.crossover(bull, signal)`
2. `trigger_buy = adx > adx_threshold1` and `ta.crossover(bull, signal)`

I'm fine with the signal/result related to 1st condition which is working as expected.

However, the 2nd condition signal should occur only when condition `ta.crossover(bull, signal)` is fulfilled and there's no `crossover(bull, bear)`.
I want to know if there's a way to include the condition of "no `crossover(bull, bear)`".

Please advice

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`crossover(bull, bear)` means `bull` is above `bear` because it has just crossed it over. So, you can use this as a condition.

It would be `bull > bear`. That means `bull` is still above the `bear`.

```
trigger_buy = (adx > adx_threshold1) and ta.crossover(bull, signal) and (bull > bear)
```